# Adding same key name values

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I want to add data with same key name but different values, how can I do it without replacing the existing ones? For example the database looks like this:

```
database
   |______user1
           |______sameKey: data1
           |______sameKey: data2
```

if I use: `DatabaseRef.child(user1).child("sameKey").setValue(data);`, it will overwrite the `sameKey` with the new data, but I want it to simply be a different record of data. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to display a different record with the same key, just wrap it up under a push key, which is an alafanumeric random value

```
 mDatabaseRef.child(user1).push().child("sameKey").setValue(data);
```

Now , if you just want to update the current data and not replace it

you will need to use a map and use updateChildren take a look at this example

```
   Map<String,Object> mapData = new HashMap<>();
    mapData.put("sameKey",data);
    mDatabaseRef.child(user1).child(sameKey).updateChildren(mapData).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                // Write was successful!
                // ...
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // Write failed
                // ...
            }
        });
```

with this you will only replace data that is updated and not the entire node

take a look at **Updating or deleting** data here

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=en

Comment: It still replaces the existing one, There is something missing, maybe I must give it a sub-child with a unique-id somehow?

Comment: see the edit, just place push() before the sameKey child, that will push a new random value for that key, and you can use the same key under a pushid